# Bower installing issue

Tags: node.js, bower

I am new with Bower,and trying to install in my machine(Windows 8.1) through the cmd,but nothing happens.

I type

```
npm install -g bower
```

Then this comes up

```
   C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bower -> C:\Program 
   Files\Git\usr\local\node_modu
   les\bower\bin\bower
   C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local -- bower@1.8.0
```

`

I can see that bower is installed in C:\Program

```
C:\Users\Theodosios\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.
```

Next I change the system's PATH variable to

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA  
Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%
SystemRoot%\System 
32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program   
Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files  
(x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\Theodosios\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

However commands bower init or bower -v don't work,

What is the problem? Please advice.

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: When I type bower init or bower --version,bower is not not recognised.

Comment: C:\Users\Theodosios>bower --version
'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.